# Syncing of files in a filesystem on a clustered environment

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a Java based CRUD service which allows creation, retrieval, update and delete of files on/from the filesystem. This service can be deployed in a clustered environment.

1. Are there any design patterns or solutions which can help sync these files between the nodes in a cluster?
2. Can the folders be configured for sync?
3. Is there a chance (e.g. in case of an update) that a user on one node will not get the updated file?

I am fine with solutions that are tomcat, websphere or weblogic specific.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically want to code this yourself, why not use a distributed file system like [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29) or, if you would like something Java-based, the [Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS)](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/) instead. [More information can be found here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_file_system)

Comment: Thank you. Will check on NFS and Hadoop. Will Hadoop guarantee a proper sync?

Comment: Don't mix Hadoop and HDFS, they are separate tools. HDFS will keep sync. The question is usually more one of sync speed, though.. Depending on a lot of factors, it might take some time to sync between nodes.

Comment: Because in my case, we need consistent (or rather real time) file data whichever node it is accessed from, I guess NFS would be a better solution. Thanks for the clarification on HDFS and Hadoop.

Comment: In that case you should probably not use a distributed file system, but instead have all of the nodes access a central file store. NFS will provide that.